# Using state machines with a lot of transaction conditionals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, e-commerce, ruby-on-rails-4, state-machine

I am writing an e-commerce platform on rails 4 similar to [kickstarter](http://kickstarter.com) or [indiegogo](http://www.indiegogo.com/).  What state a product is in is highly dependent on various conditions like if there are enough orders.  So for example if I were to use the gem [`state_machine`](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine) my code might look something like this.

```
class Product  < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders

  state_machine :initial => :prelaunch do
    event :launch do
      transition :prelaunch => :pending, :if => lambda {|p| p.launch_at <= Time.now }
    end

    event :fund do
      transition :pending => :funded, :if => :has_enough_orders?
    end
  end

  def has_enough_orders?
    if orders.count > 10
  end
end
```

Then I would probably create a model observer so that every time an order is placed I check `product.has_enough_orders?` and if that returns `true` I would call `product.fund!`.  So `has_enough_orders?` is being checked multiple times.  That just doesn't seem very efficient.

Additionally `product.launch!` has a similar issue.  The best way I can think to implement it is to use something like [`sidekiq`](http://mperham.github.io/sidekiq/) and have a job that checks if any pre-launched products are passed their `launch_at` time.  However this seems equally dirty.

Am I just over thinking it or is this how you normally would use a state machine?

Answer (score 5):

I just modified your  state machine to better way to handle conditions.

You can use `after_transition` or `before_transition` methods

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders

  state_machine :initial => :prelaunch do
    after_transition :prelaunch, :do => :check_launch
    after_transition :pending, :do => :has_enough_orders?

    event :launch do
      transition :prelaunch => :pending
    end

    event :fund do
      transition :pending => :funded
    end
  end

  def check_launch
    if launch_at <= Time.now
      self.launch # call event :launch
    else
      # whatever you want
    end
  end

  def has_enough_orders?
    if orders.count > 10
      self.fund # call event :fund
    else
      # whatever you want
    end
  end
end
```